# Root finding algorithms for complex functions

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, bisection

Is there an analogue for bisection (or the golden section method), i.e., solving $f(x) = 0$ when $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

When $f$ is real-valued, we know (at least one) root exists if there exist a bracket $x_l < x_u$ such that $f(x_l)f(x_u) < 0$, in which case $x_l$ and $x_u$ "sandwich" the root. So we iteratively shrink the bracket in a way that preserves $f(x_l)f(x_u) < 0$.

My question is, is there an analogue for this when $f$ is complex valued.  Specifically, is there a condition similar to $f(x_l)f(x_u) < 0$ for "sandwiching" the root?

Comment: There is something like Weyl's quad-tree method, Didier-Yakoubsohn bisect-exclusion, other subdivisions in collections of overlapping circles like in the Lehmer–Schur algorithm,... The methods employed to exclude regions with no roots are a little more involved than comparing signs.